# Louco e doido são sempre intercambiáveis?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, sinônimos

Embora tenham basicamente o mesmo significado, existem termos ou idiomas em que uma dessas duas palavras soa bem e a outra não?  Soaria não idiomático o uso de uma das duas palavras em alguma das expressões abaixo?

- louco/doido de amor
- louco/doido de raiva
- louco/doido varrido
- deu a louca/doida nele
- ele é louco/doido por ela
- meteu-se em uma louca/doida aventura
- de médico e de louco/doido...,

Comment: Em Portugal, "de génio e de louco..." :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grosso modo, *maluco*, *louco*, *doido*, etc. são sinônimos, e acredito que os dois primeiros são usados com mais frequência em geral (dentro e fora de expressões) e que *doido* é o mais coloquial e talvez possa ter uma conotação ligeiramente mais cômica.

Mas responderia que **não**, não são *sempre* intercambiáveis: certamente há expressões em que uma das palavras é mais comum (e, portanto, soa melhor) que as outras. Analisar a frequência com que as expressões aparecem em textos -- mas **normalizando** pela frequência com que as palavras aparecem em geral, fora da expressão [1] -- seria talvez a melhor abordagem (essa pergunta inclusive talvez seja *opinion based*), mas, de qualquer forma, compartilho minhas impressões:

- *louco/doido de amor*: ambos, mas **louco** é mais comum;
- *louco/doido de raiva*: ambos, mas **louco** é mais comum;
- *louco/doido varrido*: ambos, mas **doido** é mais comum;
- *deu a louca/doida nele*: ambos, mas **louca** é mais comum;
- *ele é louco/doido por ela*: ambos, e também *maluco*;
- *meteu-se em uma louca/doida aventura*: ambos, mas **louca** é mais comum;
- *de médico e de louco/doido...*: **louco**;
- *doido/louco de pedra*: ambos, mas **doido** é mais comum;

[1]: Por exemplo, se "louco de amor" for duas vezes mais frequente que "doido de amor", mas "louco" também for duas vezes mais frequente que "doido", em geral, isso significaria que ambas as possibilidades são igualmente aceitáveis, com "doido" apenas sendo menos comum globalmente, não apenas na expressão.

Comment: É común usar expressões como FWIW (for what it's worth - Google traduze como 'por que vale a pena') em portugûes?

Comment: @KyleA Entre pessoas que conhecem a expressão, eu diria que sim. Pensando bem, acho que não é recomendável usar aqui. Vou fazer um pergunta pedindo por traduções, porque não me ocorre nenhuma.

Comment: @KyleA Se você tiver uma boa ideia uma expressão equivalente, pode responder a pergunta: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5394/2764. Nessa postagem troquei por "de qualquer maneira".

Comment: "se "louco de amor" for duas vezes mais frequente que "doido de amor", mas..." muito bem lembrado.