# Há uma boa tradução para FWIW (for what it's worth)?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

A abreviação FWIW (do inglês *for what it's worth*) [é usada](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for-what-it-s-worth) quando se dá uma informação cuja utilidade ou importância é incerta.

Exemplo:
*For what it's worth, I think he may be right.*
Não sei se minha opinião importa, mas eu penso que ele pode ter razão.

Essa é uma abreviação útil e por vezes usada informalmente em português também, mas não creio que ela seja conhecida o bastante para que se possa usá-la sem restrições - apesar de ela já estar dicionarizada (e.g., na [infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/FWIW)). No entanto não encontro uma boa tradução, embora, dependendo do contexto, algumas possibilidades talvez sejam:

- caso interesse,
- talvez não importe, mas
- de qualquer maneira/modo
- valendo o que quer que valha
- ...?

Comment: Caso interesse, também se diz *caso interesse*.

Comment: Boa, @Jacinto, vou incluir na pergunta.

Comment: É sempre complexo traduzir expressões idiomáticas! Podemos nos aproximar do sentido, mas nunca será apenas um mas sim uma aproximação! As e.i. são pura lingua, apareceram da lingua falada... ou seja, antes de uma lingua ser normatizada, regras, gramática, etc.

Answer (score 8):

*Para que conste* é talvez a melhor opção. Outra é *vale o que vale, mas...*.

Comment: "para que conste" é a melhor até agora.

Comment: para que conste é for the record....

Comment: @Lambie Bom ponto.

Comment: @stafusa É uma expressão que preciso interpretar frequentemente em depoimentos......

Answer (score 5):

Eu creio que o português não tenha uma tradução direta para ***For what it's Worth*** e nem para a versão abreviada FWIW.

Eu acho que "De qualquer maneira" é bom, mas nem sempre transmite o mesmo significado.

> **De qualquer maneira**, vamos para o restaurante! Já está muito tarde. - **Anyways**, let's go to the restaurant. It's getting late already.

Eu pessoalmente sou bem literal quando quero expressar algo parecido com FWIW.

> **Eu não sei se será de grande ajuda**, mas o meu tio é professor de inglês. Posso perguntar a ele. - **For what it's Worth**, my uncle is an English teacher. I could ask him.

Só lembrando que estou usando PT/BR.

Comment: "Não sei se será de grande/alguma ajuda, mas" é uma boa opção.

Comment: @stafusa acho que você acaba tendo que ser literal nesse caso. Mas existem muitos pontos na língua portuguesa nos quais você conseguirá abreviar coisas que não consegue no inglês :)

Answer (score 5):

"Se [isso] vale de algo" pode ser uma boa opção. É comum em PT-BR.

Answer (score 3):

Tanto quanto sei que não existe nenhuma tradução directa, mas poderá ser também um equivalente válido da expressão *"seja como for*" ou "*assim como assim*"

> For what it's worth, I think he may be right.

"*Seja como for, acho que ele tem razão*"

Comment: Concordo, também está ficando claro para mim que não há nenhuma expressão suficientemente equivalente - mas tenho um entendimento diferente sobre o "seja como for": vejo nele uma conotação de insistência na opinião, por exemplo, conforme o contexto, "independentemente disto", "apesar daquilo", etc., um significado quase oposto ao "não sei se será de alguma ajuda" [sugerido](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5395/2764) pelo Felipe.

Comment: Não existe tradução direta de nada. Só existem sentidos equivalentes....concordo com esta resposta.

Comment: @Lambie "Não existe tradução direta de nada" - a rigor pode ser verdade, pelo menos na linguagem cotidiana (termos técnicos frequentemente têm traduções diretas exatas), mas é também útil notar que existem diferentes graus de equivalência.

Comment: @stafua Só posso repetir que nem papagaio: No ensino da tradução e interpretação, se fala em traduzir ideias e sentidos das palavras. Existe equivalência de sentido, não das palavras em si. Só digo o que se diz na profissão....O fato de existir exatidão não muda essa "verdade". A tradução correta de qualquer verbete técnico ou não contravem à esta ideia.... :)

Comment: @Lambie Acredito que seja você quem esteja interpretando de forma errônea a frase "não existe tradução direta", esta frase já subentende tudo o que você acabou de dizer. "Não existe um termo que reflita o exato significado de 'FWIW', apenas coisas que se assemelham". Diferente de termos como "btw" que com certeza tem termos que refletem o mesmo significado de maneira exata.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira  Se você não estudou tradução e não deseja saber o que se diz na profissão, deixemos o assunto. Não vale a pena para mim gastar energia nisso. ///seja como for=be that as it may.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth quer dizer em inglês, if there is any relevance to what I'm saying.....

Em português, poderia se exprimir por: se tiver cabimento ou se for pertinente ou relevante.

Comment: Também boas sugestões.

Comment: Quase um ano e meio depois, meu upvote.

Comment: @stafusa Essas preguntas me deixam um poquinho angustiada. Agradeço seu voto. Infelizmente, o jogo é regido pelos que nem tem ideia do que é. :)

Answer (score 2):

Como não há tradução direta, podemos adaptar **dependendo do contexto**.

Em alguns casos eu usaria algo como:

> "De qualquer forma, minha opinião é esta..."

Em outros casos, usaria algo:

> Não sei se ajuda, mas eu penso que ..."

PS: Meu Português é do sul do Brasil.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que "a quem interessar possa..."  pode ser uma aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

**Também digno de nota** me parece uma tradução muito adequada

Comment: Boas vindas e obrigado pela resposta. Tenho impressão de que essa expressão não transmite o pouco comprometimento com a relevância do que se segue, que a expressão original em inglês tem.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que valha.

Pelo que valha, essa joia esta cara.

FWIW this jewel is not good (cheap).

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas, por exemplo com referências. No caso de "pelo que valha" não encontrei, numa busca rápida, nenhum exemplo em que ela é usada com esse sentido — você poderia apresentar algum? Obrigado.